# Swift - how do I pass the type through a method call?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

A Realm object:

```
class Dog: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var age = 0
}
```

Calling results:

```
let results = realm.objects(Dog)
```

Or doing it this way:

```
let type = Dog.self
let results = realm.objects(type)
```

I want to be able to do it by passing into a method like this:

```
class SomeClass {
  func callRealm(type: AnyObject) {
    let results = realm.objects(type)
  }
}

let someClass = SomeClass()
let type = Dog.self
someClass.callRealm(type)
```

How would I do this? I've had no luck with generics, although I think this might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `callRealm` should take input as `AnyClass` instead of `AnyObject`.

```
func callRealm(type: AnyClass) {
    let results = realm.objects(type)
  }
```